# Reading azure devops variable groups

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-devops-rest-api

I am looking for a way to read Azure DevOps variables in Library to an array,hastable or table format.

The variable names and values in azure devops variable group are something like:

repo1_name    master-20211112
repo2_name    release-20211010

I am using the api (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/distributedtask/variablegroups/get-variable-groups-by-id?view=azure-devops-rest-6.0) to get the contents of the variable group and the output is something like below:

```
repo1_name                repo2_name 
                                                                                                
@{value=master-20211112} @{value=release-20211010}
```

I need to read these variables so I can compare them with other variable group values.

Comment: Based on the above context , we understood that you want to read 2 different variable from different groups & compare them. You can refer this [Blog post](https://medium.com/objectsharp/compare-two-variable-groups-c8476f9fabf7) here they have created a bash script that gets variables from two variable groups in Azure DevOps and compares them using Azure DevOps REST API.

Comment: Thank you@VenkateshDodda-MT  . I was able to use that script in the blog to write powershell (i am on windows) script. Only thing having trouble with is the diff at the end.  diff <(jq -S '.' variablegroup1_content.json) <(jq -S '.' variablegroup2_content.json)   Can i please get the powershell equivalent of this ?

Comment: you can use `compare-object` in PowerShell to compare two set of objects which is similar to diff in bash here is the [reference documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/compare-object?view=powershell-5.1) how to work with  compare-object.
----------
You can also refer this [ServerFault](https://serverfault.com/questions/5598/how-do-i-diff-two-text-files-in-windows-powershell) discussion for more information 
-------------